# Need assistance with AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, populate

I have an Activity on which I have a Button, now what I want is that when I click on the button I want an AlertDialog to load a layout which I have made. I also have a ListView inside the layout and I have built an Adapter for the ListView. but I cannot populate the ListView with some data.

I hope I made the question clear.

eg : layout name : searchfood.xml
this layout contains a ListView named : listView1
now I need to load this "searchfood.xml" in the AlertDialog and populate the "listView1" with data for which I have already made an Adapter extending BaseAdapter.

The Adapter is working fine because when I open the searchfood.xml as an Activity with the necessary configurations it works fine....It just doesn't work with the AlertDialog.............  :(